# Batch file to copy multiple files by using partial filename

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy multiple files from source to destination and the first 8 letters of the files are same so by using this partial file name i would like to copy and content of the files also should be replaced with string while copying.
for example:
I have three file in source path and those are like below

1. samefile123.txt
2. samefile456.txt
3. myfile.txt
4. ratefile.txt

I want to pick up the first two files because the first 8 letters of the files are same and if the files have content like `apple` or `banana` or `grape` words those words should be replace with `papaya`.

Comment: This site is for helping you to fix your code, please take the [tour] and read up on [ask], before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53214501/edit), formatting the code correctly using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

To copy multiple text files with the same name using batch you need to use a wildcard.   Here is what I have tested on my computer and it works.

```
xcopy "C:\%username%\desktop\test\samefi*.txt" "C:\users\%username%\desktop"
```

For more information on the uses of xcopy use:

```
xcopy /?
```

You can read more on wildcards [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html).

If I could get more information on the second part about changing the name from grape to papaya I may assist with that.